# How to get the fraction of occurrences of a certain value in a Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a `DataFrame` containing a column `A` which contains only values `'foo'` and `'bar'`, and I'd like to compute the fraction of `foo`s.  One way to do this is by using Boolean selection together with the `__len__` function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                          'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                          'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                   'D' : np.random.randn(8)})

assert len(df[df['A'] == 'foo']) / len(df) == 0.625
```

However, I feel that this can also be done in a more `pandas`-native way using `groupby` and `count`. For example,

```
print(df.groupby('A').count() / len(df))
```

yields

```
         B      C      D
A                       
bar  0.375  0.375  0.375
foo  0.625  0.625  0.625
```

What is the recommended way to proceed? Do I just select the at `foo` in any column?

Comment: Also, `df['A'].eq('foo').mean()`?

Comment: If performance is a requirement, it might be also be faster to operate on the `np.ndarray`, using something like `(df.A.values == 'foo').mean()`; compared to `(df.A == 'foo').mean()`, that saves about a factor of three on a 10000000 row data frame here.

Comment: Maybe `df.A.value_counts()/len(df)`

Answer (score 4):

The pandas-native way is `series.value_counts(normalize=True)`:

```
df.A.value_counts(normalize=True)

foo    0.625
bar    0.375
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

This shows all values, so if you're interested only in a single value and want the best performance, then the method from @fuglede's comment is better:

```
(df.A.values == 'foo').mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Wen's comment:

```
In [10]: df.A.value_counts()['foo']/len(df)
Out[10]: 0.625
```